# Session not work in exec file php

Tags: php, session, exec

I created a PHP file and runs with an exec. At the end of the process, send an email, but I should also delete a session variable, but it does not work.

Ex file 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['upgrade'] = $id;
exec('php up.php > /dev/null &');
```

ex file up.php

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['upgrade']);
```

but unset($_SESSION['upgrade']); not work.

Comment: does it give any error ?? or what

Comment: is defined SESSION, looks not, becose there is not previous navigation who define it

Comment: you forgot to start session in your first file. So code need to be:-`session_start();SESSION['upgrade'] = $id;exec('php up.php > /dev/null &');`

Comment: session_start() is already present at the beginning of the code

Comment: No solution to this problem?